# How to set default value for select dropdown using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

setDefaultValue function is called when operation is changed on the page so when one operation is done i want to set dropDown value to `JavaScript` using Jquery thats not happening with below code , what is implemented wrong ?

dropdown text should say `JavaScript`

main.html

```
<div style="text-align: right;margin: 5px;margin-left: 45%">
    <select name="dropDownSelect"  onchange="handleDropDown(this.value)">
        <option value="JS" selected="selected">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="TS">TypeScript</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

main.js

```
function setDefaultValue () {
    $("#dropDownSelect").val('JavaScript');
}
```

Comment: How do you call `setDefaultValue`? Any errors in your console?

Comment: Do you want to add this option as hack in additon  to JS and TS? or you mean that JS?

Comment: @j08691 no error in console , setDefaultValue is being called in another method and when i set break point it does go to the line in setDefaultValue but Values stays to the last selected that was TypeScript

Comment: @AliSheikhpour yes i meant JS

Comment: The "value" is `JS` and not `JavaScript`

Comment: Where do you have an element with the ID `dropDownSelect` for `$("#dropDownSelect")` to match?

Comment: came back to Jquery after years , implementation was using name attribute.

Comment: Given that the option that you want to automatically/programatically select has the `selected="selected"` attribute, that should already be doing what you seem to want: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mfouxn6w/ (note that I added another option ahead of the `value="JS"` in order to show that the browser isn't just selecting the first `<option>`.

Comment: @David Thomas dropdown  is being called in every api call to set the values, now if user choose typescript for first api and go to another api call dropdown show show javascript at that time it alwasy contains last description , context is correct but the dropdown description remaining the last one

Comment: So you have multiple `<select>` elements, each of which is filled by an API call? Or after choosing an `<option>` in one `<select>` another `<select>` element is created and added to the page? I think you need to take a step back and look at your question. Please [edit] the question in order to give us the necessary information, as well as what actions the user takes and what the responses are and should be.

Comment: problem is not with the element or with context displaying on the page , when setDefaulValue is called dropdown text should say "JavaScript" thats i all iam trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if you just need to change the selected value of the drop down:

```
$("select[name='dropDownSelect'] option[value='TS']").attr('selected','selected');
```

If there is an event bind on the drop down change, or any function is called, try this:

```
$("select[name='dropDownSelect'] option[value='TS']").attr('selected','selected');
$("select[name='dropDownSelect']").trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this like

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
    <option value="1">Value one</option>
    <option value="2">Value two</option>
    <option value="3">Value three</option>
</select>

$("#myselect option[value=2]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function addOption() { 
    optionText = 'Value two'; 
    optionValue = 'Value two'; 

    $('#select1').append(`<option value="${optionValue}"> 
     ${optionText} 
     </option>`); 
  } 
</script>
```